# Using a C# variable from a custom control in xaml (silverlight)

Tags: c#, xaml, custom-controls

I have looked a a lot of other post, regarding this topic, but now i have spent more then a day, trying to get something to work, but i will try to aske the qustion here, and hope you can help me.

I want to make a custom control where i can add values in the property menu, where i add the control inside my project, it need to be something new each time.

And the info i need to a resource control in xaml, but i can not bind the strings from C# to what i need in xaml:

The C# code:

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Ink;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Animation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows.Threading;
using WFSilverlight.Shared;
using WFSilverlight.Core;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using BG_CalgaryNC_11611.Controls;

namespace BG_CalgaryNC_11611
{
public partial class BG_Calgary_Text_Nav : UserControl
{
    //public string NavPage = String.Empty;
    [Category("BG")]
    public string PageToNavigate { get; set; }

    [Category("BG")]
    public string DesciptionPageName { get; set; }

    [Category("BG")]
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }

    public BG_Calgary_Text_Nav()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        NavText.Text = DisplayName;
        NavPage = "BG_CalgaryNC_11611_" + PageToNavigate;

        //this.DataContext = this;
        //NavText.Resources.Add("navPageResourse", NavPage);
        //NavText.Resources.Add("displayNameResourse", DesciptionPageName);

    }

    public string NavPage { get; set; }
}
}
```

Where i want to use "NavPage" and "DesciptionPageName" to add then in xaml.

The xaml code:

```
    <UserControl
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
xmlns:BG_CalgaryNC_11611_Controls="clr-namespace:BG_CalgaryNC_11611.Controls" 
xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
mc:Ignorable="d"

x:Class="BG_CalgaryNC_11611.BG_Calgary_Text_Nav"
d:DesignWidth="640" d:DesignHeight="480">

<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Cursor="Hand">
    <Viewbox HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <TextBlock x:Name="NavText" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="10.667" FontWeight="Bold" Text="TC9-21" Height="16" Width="43">
            <TextBlock.Resources>
                <BG_CalgaryNC_11611_Controls:TranslatableCPNavItem Description="{Binding NavPage, Mode=OneWay}" Source="{Binding DesciptionPageName, Mode=OneWay}" x:Key="target1"/>
            </TextBlock.Resources>
            <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseLeftButtonUp">
                    <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding NavigatToCommand, Mode=OneWay}" CommandParameter="{StaticResource target1}"/>
                </i:EventTrigger>
            </i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <TextBlock.Foreground>
                <SolidColorBrush Color="{StaticResource BG_ConnectionArrow_Color}"/>
            </TextBlock.Foreground></TextBlock>
    </Viewbox>
</Grid>
```

I can build the project, but when i add the custom control, i get this error:

object of type 'system.windows.data.binding' cannot be converted to type 'system.string'

Hope you can help me.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that the problem is in this line

```
    <BG_CalgaryNC_11611_Controls:TranslatableCPNavItem Description="{Binding NavPage, Mode=OneWay}" Source="{Binding DesciptionPageName, Mode=OneWay}" x:Key="target1"/>
```

You haven't provided the source of your `TranslatableCPNavItem` class, so I'm going to have to make an assumption based on the code of another class you've provided above.  I'm guessing that the `Description` property within this class is implemented as a 'simple' property, such as

```
    public string Description { get; set; }
```

You can't apply a `Binding` to a property such as this.  If you want a property to be set using a binding, it needs to be a [dependency property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221408%28v=vs.95%29.aspx).  It should instead look something like the following:

```
    public string Description
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(DescriptionProperty); }
        set { SetValue(DescriptionProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty DescriptionProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Description",
                                    typeof(string),
                                    typeof(TranslateableCPNavItem),
                                    null);
```

This does look like quite a lot to type in for each property that you want to use with bindings, but there is a `propdp` code snippet that generates most of it for you.